# asyncio.create_task without awaiting result

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to make sense of asyncio, specifically the `await` keyword.

This is my code:

```
async def sleep_and_print(s: str):

   print(f'{datetime.utcnow()} Executing sleep_and_print({s})')
   await asyncio.sleep(1)
   print(f'{datetime.utcnow()} Completed sleep_and_print({s})')

async def main():

   asyncio.create_task(sleep_and_print(0))
   asyncio.create_task(sleep_and_print(1))
   asyncio.create_task(sleep_and_print(2))

   asyncio.gather(*[sleep_and_print(i) for i in range(3)])

if __name__ == "__main__":

   asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is:

```
2021-10-14 10:08:03.242891 Executing sleep_and_print(0)
2021-10-14 10:08:03.242891 Executing sleep_and_print(1)       
2021-10-14 10:08:03.242891 Executing sleep_and_print(2)       
2021-10-14 10:08:03.243896 Executing sleep_and_print(0)       
2021-10-14 10:08:03.243896 Executing sleep_and_print(1)       
2021-10-14 10:08:03.243896 Executing sleep_and_print(2)       
_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=CancelledError()>
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

I have two initial questions:

1. Why is the behaviour different when creating three tasks with `create_task()` compared with the tasks being created by `gather()`? I understand that `gather()` will submit the tasks for execution concurrently whereas the `create_task()` tasks will be submitted individually. I do not understand why `gather()` result in an exception.
2. Why is it that this task will begin but not complete execution

   `asyncio.create_task(sleep_and_print(0))`

   Whereas both of these will complete, even though only the second is awaited on

   ```
   asyncio.create_task(sleep_and_print(0))
   await asyncio.create_task(sleep_and_print(1))
   ```

Answer (score 4):

`create_task` is synchronous: it merely submits the task to the event loop and returns immediately.

> Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return the Task object.

Thus if you await it you just await the task object, thus `await create_task(fn())` is functionally equivalent to `await fn()`.

`gather()` is *asynchronous*.  You *have* to await it, otherwise you just get the coro it returns, or more accurately, the `Futures` object.  The exception is being thrown when the loop ends, since `gather()` has never actually been run (since nothing awaited it).

More generally, the effect of `await` from *your* point of view is to pause execution until the result is 'in' and then continue.  The effect from the *code's* point of view is to yield back to the event loop and stop running until the condition awaited is satisfied, at which point the event loop *might* decide, next time something yields to it and it gets to choose which task to run, to go back to your task and keep running.  (It might not as well: remember that asyncio will never continue *before* the awaited is complete, but continuing straight afterwards is best-effort.  Thus if you `await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)` you will likely end up waiting longer than you expected.  This is rarely a problem on real hardware, but it can make writing asynchronous drivers in things like `micropython` a little harder.)

`create task` is an idiom for 'run this pretty soon'. (If you've written ISRs, you may have used similar strategies to avoid running too much code in the interrupt context, when you need to run a moderately expensive callback on some event.)  Note that if you call `create_task` from *within* the event loop and do not yield (by awaiting something) the task will never run; likewise if the loop ends, it will never run (as here, since `run` only runs until `main` is finished).

Note that it is perfectly meaningful to generate a coro and then await it later:

```py
async def my_fn():
   await asyncio.sleep(56)

long_fn = my_fn()
...
await long_fn
```

You might do this when e.g. passing coros as arguments to functions, or storing them in class attributes.  Coros are every bit as much first-class citizens as functions in python.

### References

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather

(note the use of *awaitable* to specify that the object returned needs to be awaited)

### P.S.

Note that I use 'yield' here in the coroutine sense of 'give up control to the scheduler' rather than in the generator sense of 'send some value'.  There was a time in python when we mixed those two together, but thankfully the days of generator based coroutines are over.  It *worked*, but it got very confusing to follow very quickly.

Comment: Thanks. A few follow-ups, because I am clearly misunderstanding:

> You can await create_task, but it makes no difference

It does seem to make a difference. If I await it, the task completes. If I do not await it, the program terminates before the task completes. 

> Note that if you do not yield (by awaiting something) the task will never run

This is the opposite of what I am seeing. Without any await statements in the task, it completes.

Comment: @paxtell in both cases I was extremely misleading in what I wrote: I've clarified.  In the first case I was actually *wrong*, since I had forgotten that `create_task` returned the task object.  My comment in the second case was aimed at creating tasks *within the loop* to offload execution when we don't care when it runs, rather than creating tasks *before starting the loop*.  I guess I spend too much time in embedded contexts where everything is asynchronous after a few seconds of booting....